# CSS Unwanted padding in IE using floats

Tags: html, css, layout, css-float

It's been a long day of designing and I ran into a problem today. The website www.dcninc.com/newtest/security_testing.php is a new design I'm working on at work right now.

If you view it in Firefox you will notice there is no padding on the 2 right boxes (I did that on purpose to trouble shoot my problem) However if you view that same page in IE, it adds padding to the right side. Here is my CSS and HTML below.

- http://pastebin.com/hRxZp9ub
- http://pastebin.com/YwSYn7ti

Comment: even when I float the grey boxes left, they still add extra padding to the right side.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to add this to the header

```
<!--[if lt IE 8]>
    <script src="http://ie7-js.googlecode.com/svn/version/2.0(beta3)/IE8.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<![endif]-->
```

Answer (score 2):

You have elements nested within each other that have widths of 250.

Like this,

```
<table width="250"><tr width="250"></tr><table width="250"></table></table>
```

Since there has been some width used up with padding, there is not 250 pixels of free space for you to put inside the table. I would try lowering the width of the inner elements by 10-20 pixels.

Hope this helps. Here's the markup I was referencing,

```
<table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="250">
<tr>
<td width="250" height="9" style="background:url(Images/right_box_gray_top.png) no-repeat;"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td style="background:url(Images/right_box_gray_middle.png) repeat-y" width="250">
<div class="list-right-info">
<table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="250">
<tr>
<td width="40"><img src="Images/icons/phonepic.jpg" border="0" /></td>
<td><center>CALL US TODAY<br /> 800.xxx.xxxx</center></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td></td>
<td></td>
</tr>
</table>
</div>
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td style="background:url(Images/right_box_gray_bottom.png) no-repeat" width="250" height="108"></td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Comment: by putting<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.1//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml11/DTD/xhtml11.dtd">
in my header it has now fixed all my problems :)

Comment: you're information was not the solution, thank you for pointing that out however it is not affecting my site what so ever. The answer below from FDisk helped.